# Do we need the [pedagogy] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just noticed we have a [pedagogy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) tag.

It has no tag wiki, only 7 questions, which are all about how to explain something, or what a good example would be for explaining something.

The oldest publicly visible "pedagogy" question dates from 2009. Back then, it was probably on-topic, but Stack Overflows scope has significantly narrowed since those early days.

I think this tag is off-topic for today's Stack Overflow, and should be burninated.

Comment: Why are you asking and not just retagging/closing/downvoting?bIt's done fast.

Comment: @Deduplicator To see if the community agrees. I can work on it tonight if I have a little spare time.

Comment: Well, I hope any other actions needed on those questions was taken while they were being edited, since we can't find them anymore :P

Comment: @Wooble: I DV/UV/CV and edited some other things too, as seemed appropriate. Some of them really only had to loose that ill-fated tag. With only 7 questions, that's easy enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aaaand it's gone!

(whenever the script prunes tags...)